# How do change all filenames with a similar but not identical structure?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, file, command-line

Due to a variety of complex photo library migrations that had to be done using a combination of manual copying and importing tools that renamed the files, it seems I wound up with a ton of files with a similar structure. Here's an example:

```
2009-05-05 - 2009-05-05 - IMG_0486 - 2009-05-05 at 10-13-43 - 4209 - 2009-05-05.JPG
```

What it should be:

```
2009-05-05 - IMG_0486.jpg
```

The other files have the same structure, but obviously the individual dates and IMG numbers are different.

Is there any way I can do some command line magic in Terminal to automatically rename these files to the shortened/correct version?

Comment: File names should retain the spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you may have sub-directories and want to find all files inside this directory tree.

This first code block (which you could put in a script) is "safe" (does nothing), but will help you see what would be done.

```
datep="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]"
dir="PUT_THE_FULL_PATH_OF_YOUR_MAIN_DIRECTORY"
while IFS= read -r file
do
  name="$(basename "$file")"
  [[ "$name" =~ ^($datep)\ -\ $datep\ -\ ([^[:space:]]+)\ -\ $datep.*[.](.+)$ ]] || continue
  date="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  imgname="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  ext="${BASH_REMATCH[3],,}"
  dir_of_file="$(dirname "$file")"
  target="$dir_of_file/$date - $imgname.$ext"
  echo "$file"
  echo "  would me moved to..."
  echo "    $target"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f)
```

Make sure the output is what you want and are expecting.  I cannot test on your actual files, and if this script does not produce results that are entirely satisfactory, I do not take any responsibility for hair being pulled out.  Do not blindly let anyone (including me) mess with your precious data by copy and pasting code from the internet if you have no reliable, checked backup.

Once you are sure, decide if you want to take a chance on some guy's code written without any opportunity for testing and replace the three consecutive lines beginning with `echo` with this :

```
mv "$file" "$target"
```

Note that file names have to match to a pretty strict pattern to be considered for processing, so if you notice that some files are not being processed, then the pattern may need to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are all the *exact* same structure, spaces and everything, you can use `awk` to split the names up using the spaces as break points. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=""

for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    unset output #clear variable from previous loop
    output="$(echo $file | awk '{print $1}')" #Assign the first field to the output variable
    output="$output"" - " #Append with [space][dash][space]
    output="$output""$(echo $file | awk '{print $5}')" #Append with IMG_* field
    output="$output""." #Append with period
    #Use -F '.' to split by period, and $NF to grab the last field (to get the extension)
    output="$output""$(echo $file | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')"
done
```

From there, something like `mv /path/to/files/$file /path/to/files/$output` as a final line in the file loop will rename the file. I'd copy a few files into another folder to test with first, since we're dealing with file manipulation.

All the output assigning lines can be consolidated into a single line, as well, but it's less easy to read.

```
output="$(echo $file | awk '{print $1 " - " $5 "."}')""$(echo $file | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')"
```

You'll still want a file loop, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to convert the filename with the first date and the IMG* name, you can run the following on the folder:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for file in *
do
printf "mv '$file' '"
printf '%s' $(cut -d" " -f1,4,5 <<< "$file")
printf "'.jpg"
done | sh
```

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), edit your answer accordingly to avoid getting down-voted. This will not work

Comment: I've added `IFS=$'\n'` for precisely that reason. I tried it on my local machine and it worked

Comment: Refer the shared link, _Also notice how ls sometimes garbles your filename data (in our case, it turned the newline character in between the words "a" and "newline" into a question mark. Some systems put a \n instead.). On some systems it doesn't do this when its output isn't a terminal, on others it always mangles the filename. All in all, you really can't and shouldn't trust the output of ls to be a true representation of the filenames that you want to work with. So don't._, I am not going to down vote it, but it is not the most efficient ways of doing so, use `find`!